# fill max values in a rose plot in matlab

Tags: matlab, fill, rose-plot

I use rose in Matlab and I want to color those triangles with values above the 95 percentile (max outliers) red. I used the following generic code

```
clear all
close all
ncat = 180;
mydata = rand(360,1).*100;       % random vector
mydata = mydata./max(mydata).*100; % normalize to a max of 100
[tout, rout] = rose(mydata,ncat); % do rose plot with 180 categories

polar(tout, rout);   % getting coordinates
[xout, yout] = pol2cart(tout, rout);
set(gca, 'nextplot', 'add');
test = sum(reshape(mydata(1:360),360/ncat,[])); 
index = find( test >= prctile(test,95)); % get index of outliers
for cindex = index
    fill(xout((cindex-1)*4+1:cindex*4), yout((cindex-1)*4+1:cindex*4), 'r'); % fill outliers red
end
set(gca,'View',[-90 90],'YDir','reverse'); % put 0(360) to top
```

however, the filled triangles are not the max values and I cannot figure out why. Any idea?

[image]

adding the solution suggested by @zeeMonkeez:

```
% as suggested in the answer
figure
[tout, rout] = rose(mydata,ncat); % do rose plot with 180 categories
polar(tout, rout);   % getting coordinates
[xout, yout] = pol2cart(tout, rout);
set(gca, 'nextplot', 'add');
test = rout(2:4:end);
index = find( test >= prctile(test,95)); % get index of outliers
for cindex = index
    fill(xout((cindex-1)*4+1:cindex*4), yout((cindex-1)*4+1:cindex*4), 'r'); % fill outliers red
end
set(gca,'View',[-90 90],'YDir','reverse'); % put 0(360) to top
```

does mark the highest ones

[image]

but for the original data I get

```
test1( test1 >= prctile(test1,95))
```

180.8300  190.7822  190.6257  175.4790  183.1746  196.6801  181.4798  176.1298  198.9011

```
length(test1( test1 >= prctile(test1,95)))
```

9

whereas when using rout I get for

```
test( test >= prctile(test,95))
```

4     5     5     4     5     4     4     4     4     4     4     4     5     4     4     6     4     4     5     4     4

```
length(test( test >= prctile(test,95)))
```

22

... following up on the comments and answers below (thanks a lot to @ ZeeMonkeez) and now that I understand how rose works, for those who might run into the same problem here one solution:

```
figure
catsize = 30;
counts_by_angle = round(rand(360,1).*100);

ncounts = sum(reshape(counts_by_angle(1:360),catsize,[]));
ncounts = ncounts ./max(ncounts);
bins = ((15:catsize:360)./360).*2.*pi;
cases = ones(1,round(ncounts(1).*100)).*round(bins(1),2);
for icat = 2:length(ncounts)
    cases = [cases  ones(1,round(ncounts(icat).*100)).*round(bins(icat),2)];
end
[tout, rout] = rose(cases,bins);
polar(tout, rout);
[xout, yout] = pol2cart(tout, rout);
set(gca, 'nextplot', 'add');
test = rout(2:4:end);
cindex = find( test > prctile(test,95));
for index = cindex
    fill(xout((index-1)*4+1:index*4), yout((index-1)*4+1:index*4), 'r');
end
set(gca,'View',[-90 90],'YDir','reverse');
```

Comment: Also note that the inputs to `rose` are expressed in radians, so your `mydata` variable will essentially be taken mod 2π. Not sure you are aware of this looking at your code.

Comment: I think in your example you assume `rose` takes histogram counts as inputs. It does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at `rout` (returned by `rose`), which conveniently contains the bin counts in a pattern `0 c(i) c(i) 0`, for bins `i`. If you set

```
test = rout(2:4:end);
```

you get the bin counts for all `ncat` bins. The rest of your code correctly draws the outlier bins.

Comment: @ zeeMonkeez: Thx for that. It works! However, as `rout` only contains integers identifying the highest 5% of `rout` will likely yield a different number of values in comparison to the aggregated `mydata` in the old `test`

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your problem. Do you want to find the outliers in the distribution of bin counts? That's what my answer does. If you  want to find the outliers in the data, you have to be careful, because it will be mapped around the circle mod 2π. It's not even clear what outlier means on the circle.

Comment: @ zeeMonkeez: I added the output in the question so it might get more clear what I mean

Comment: @ zeeMonkeez: Concerning the radians. If I have 360 categories it shouldn't matter right? In the help it says: The vector theta, expressed in radians, determines the angle of each bin from the origin. So if I have 360 bins they should match 2 Pi

Comment: @horseshoe Your data is in radians, so as I wrote above it will be taken mod 2π and that determines where on the circle it falls. Essentially what rose does is `histogram(mod(my data,2*pi), ncat)`, and wraps it around a circle. So `rose` takes raw data as input, not histogram counts. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ zeeMonkeez: Ok I am a bit slow and it was late, but now I finally got it, thanks. I indeed assumed that each category includes the number of counts (so the output of hist) and not the angle itself.